# Show that the set of $m\times n$ matrices is an abelian group w.r.t binary operator $+$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

**Question:** Show that the set of $m\times n$ matrices is an abelian group w.r.t binary operator $+$.

Since this question does not provide the domain of the elements in the matrix, I'm in confusion as to how exactly to show the 5 properties for Abelian Group to be true. Kindly guide me for the same. Thank you

Comment: More generally, the set of all functions $X \to A$ is an abelian group with pointwise operations. Here $X$ is a set and $A$ is an abelian group.

Comment: If you do not assume the entries of the matrices to be in an abelian group, you cannot proof that the set of these matrices is an abelian group. (At least not without adding other properties.)